# How to track ether received from smartcontracts without internal transactions?

Tags: go-ethereum, ether, binance

I want to track the ether received from smart contracts, in the case of uniswap we can track using withdraw function, but if the smart contract does not raise this event it's difficult to track the ether(native token) received.

So the only way to track this is using internal transactions?

Eg: https://bscscan.com/tx/0xdb5818508de1d5d1d88a8649d22f3483166569c3903d22e324c18c8fd4a7951e

Here the BnB was transferred to the user address but the logs do not have withdraw event.

Answer (score 1):

If the smart contract sending or receiving doesn't emit an event, then there is no way to know about the transfers without getting the transaction traces